# Which states use disproportionate punishment in case of forged travel documents?

Tags: visa, forgery, punishment

In [the Schengen visa code handbook](https://nyidanmark.dk/da/Lovstof/visa_code/visa_code_handbook) on page 60, you will find the following passage:

> **Recommended best practice** in case a false, counterfeit or forged travel document is detected:
>
> Such documents should never be returned to the holder but preferably the offence should be reported and the document transmitted to the authorities of the issuing third country. However, in case of disproportionate punishment for such offence on the part of the third state concerned, the consulate should not report the case to the authorities of third country concerned.

Which states is this paragraph referring to when it talks about “disproportionate punishment for such offence”?

Comment: I'm guessing those that would punish people who want to leave their country, such as North Korea or former DDR.

Comment: Did you ask this question before? Was deleted https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/185645/which-states-use-disproportionate-punishment-in-case-of-forged-travel-documents

Comment: Yes, I was told that the travel SE was not the right place for the question, and I was told to close and repost it by a moderator. It did not receive any answers.

Comment: It sounds like there's no official Schengen-wide list of countries here, just a general recommendation that consulates consider the effects of reporting forged travel documents. Any such decisions about what to do in individual cases would be a matter of policy for each Schengen state and possibly the discretion of consular personnel depending on the specific circumstances.

Comment: So what in this context are consular personnel?

Answer (score 5):

### Do you consider [caning](https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/punishment-for-illegally-entering-countries) disproportionate?

Both Singapore and Malaysia can punish travelling on false papers with caning.

Most EU countries have punishments of 0-3 years imprisonment (Hungary has 8), so countries that have significantly longer terms, like Botswana’s 10, might also be seen as disproportionate.

Comment: And how about Hungary’s 8?